# How to find using db2 query if my matching item is in first row or not

Tags: db2

I have a movie database in `DB2`.It has one field as class with around 15-16 distinct element in class field  and another field is `Day_of_year`. Each `day_of_year` has ticket sales for almost all the classes & in database the order of appearance of class elements varies in some random order, not based on ticket sales.  I want to find `day_of_year where gold_class` (an element in class field)
appears as first record
Can you please suggest me the query to do that?

So data type for day_of_year is INTEGER &  class is  VARCHAR(40)
Here is my sample data

```
Day_of_year Class
1   Gold_Class
1   Class_A
1   Class_B
1   Class_C
1   Class_D
1   Class_E
1   Class_F
2   Class-G
2   Class-GB
2   Class-H
2   Gold_Class
2   Class-P
2   Class-K
```

I want to run a query to get the day of year having Gold_Class
 in first row. For example here it's day-1

Comment: Please post the table definition, some sample data, expected results, and the results you get from your attempted queries.

Comment: @mustaccio, added data type for those two fields. Remaining fields are not relevant.Also my sample data. Sorry I haven't try it.I'm not getting way to find the solution

Comment: Knowing that rows in a table don't have any intrinsic order, how do you determine that a row is "first"?